# The insert speed of int and binary

Tags: mysql

I read the the post: [How number of columns affects performance ?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/). It seems that the 
number of columns will slow down the insert speed dramatically. So I created two table:
The first with with 100 tinyint columns and 100 smallint columns, the second with 
one binary(100) column and one binary(200) column. So these two table have same row length.

More specially:

```
CREATE TABLE 'users'(

   'c0' tinyint(4) not null default '0',

   'd0' smallint(6) not null default '0',

   .....

   'c99' tinyint(4) not null default '0',

   'd99' smallint(6) not null default '0'

) ENGINE = InnoDB default CHARSET = utf8

CREATE TABLE 'users2'(

   'c0' binary(100) not null default '\0 *100',

   'd0' binary(200) not null default '\0 * 200'

) ENGINE = InnoDB default CHARSET = utf8
```

Then I ran the following two procedure from mysql workbench.

```
create procedure insert1()

begin

    declare v_max int default 1000;
    declare v_counter int default 0;
    while v_counter < v_max do
         insert into user (c0, d0, c1, d1....c99, d99) values (0,0,0.....0);
         set v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    end while;
end

create procedure insert2()

begin

    declare v_max int default 1000;
    declare v_counter int default 0;
    while v_counter < v_max do
         insert into users2 (c0, d0) values (0x0000...00, 0x000....00);
         set v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    end while;
end
```

The result is:

call insert1(): 0.999 sec

call insert2(): 3.479 sec

Since these two tables have the same row length, and the first one have more columns (200 columns), I expect the insert speed for the 1st table should be slower than the second one.
Can someone help explain why this happens? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you must change binary(100) to binary(4), binary(200) to binary(6).
I've heard that binary(n) is for n = 1 byte ,not binary digit.