# Does the number of columns affect the speed of sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I created two tables with sqlalchemy (python 2.7), the database is mysql 5.5.
The following is my code:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:123@localhost/test')

metadata = MetaData()

conn = engin.connect()

# For table 1:

columns = []

for i in xrange(100):

    columns.append(Column('c%d' % i, TINYINT, nullable = False, server_default = '0'))
    columns.append(Column('d%d' % i, SmallInteger, nullable = False, server_default = '0'))

user = Table('user', metadata, *columns)
# So user has 100 tinyint columns and 100 smallint columns.

# For table 2:

user2 = Table('user2', metadata,

        Column('c0', BINARY(100), nullable = False, server_default='\0'*100),
        Column('d0', BINARY(200), nullable = False, server_default='\0'*200),
)

# user2 has two columns contains 100 bytes and 200 bytes respectively. 

I then inserted 4000 rows into each table. Since these two tables have same row length, I
expect the select speed will be almost the same. I ran the following test code:

s1 = select([user]).compile(engine)

s2 = select([user2]).compile(engine)

t1 = time()

result = conn.execute(s1).fetchall()

print 't1:', time() - t1 

t2 = time()

result = conn.execute(s2).fetchall()

print 't2', time() - t2 

The result is :

t1: 0.5120000

t2: 0.0149999
```

Does this means the number of columns in table will dramatically affect the performance
of SQLAlchemy? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Does this means the number of columns in table will dramatically affect the performance of SQLAlchemy?

well thats a tough one, and it probably depends more on the underlying SQL engine, `MySQL` in this case, then actually `sqlalchemy`, which is nothing more than a way to interact with different db engines while using the same interface.

> SQLAlchemy is the Python SQL toolkit and Object Relational Mapper that gives application developers the full power and flexibility of SQL.
>
> It provides a full suite of well known enterprise-level persistence patterns, designed for efficient and high-performing database access, adapted into a simple and Pythonic domain language.

**Though I could be wrong, you could try benchmarking it using regular `SQL`.**

I actually ran some tests ...

```
import timeit

setup = """
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, select, Table, Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import BOOLEAN, SMALLINT, VARCHAR
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = False)
metadata = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
columns = []

for i in xrange(100):
    columns.append(Column('c%d' % i, VARCHAR(1), nullable = False, server_default = '0'))
    columns.append(Column('d%d' % i, VARCHAR(2), nullable = False, server_default = '00'))  
    

user = Table('user', metadata, *columns)
user.create(engine)
conn.execute(user.insert(), [{}] * 4000)

user2 = Table('user2', metadata, Column('c0', VARCHAR(100), nullable = False, server_default = '0' * 100),  \
                                 Column('d0', VARCHAR(200), nullable = False, server_default = '0' * 200))
user2.create(engine)
conn.execute(user2.insert(), [{}] * 4000)
"""

many_columns = """
s1 = select([user]).compile(engine)
result = conn.execute(s1).fetchall()
"""

two_columns = """
s2 = select([user2]).compile(engine)
result = conn.execute(s2).fetchall()
"""

raw_many_columns = "res = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM user').fetchall()"
raw_two_columns = "res = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM user2').fetchall()"

timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
timeit.Timer(raw_two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
timeit.Timer(raw_many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)

>>> timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.010751008987426758
>>> timeit.Timer(raw_two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.0099620819091796875
>>> timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.23563408851623535
>>> timeit.Timer(raw_many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.21881699562072754
```

I did find this: 
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/

which was kind of interesting though he used `max` for testing ...

I really do love sqlalchemy, so I decided to compare it using pythons own sqlite3 module

```
import timeit
setup = """
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE user (%s)' %\
          ("".join(("c%i VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, d%i VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '00' NOT NULL," % (index, index) for index in xrange(99))) +\
           "c99 VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, d99 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL"))

c.execute("CREATE TABLE user2 (c0 VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '%s' NOT NULL, d0 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '%s' NOT NULL)" % ('0'* 100, '0'*200))

conn.commit()
c.executemany('INSERT INTO user VALUES (%s)' % ('?,' * 199 + '?'), [('0',) * 200] * 4000)
c.executemany('INSERT INTO user2 VALUES (?,?)', [('0'*100, '0'*200)] * 4000)
conn.commit()
"""

many_columns = """
r = c.execute('SELECT * FROM user')
all = r.fetchall()
"""

two_columns = """
r2 = c.execute('SELECT * FROM user2')
all = r2.fetchall()
"""

timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)

>>> timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.21009302139282227
>>> timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.0083379745483398438
```

and came up with the same result, so I really do think its a database implementation not a `sqlalchemy` issue.

**DEFAULT INSERT**

```
import timeit

setup = """
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, select, Table, Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import BOOLEAN, SMALLINT, VARCHAR
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = False)
metadata = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
columns = []

for i in xrange(100):
    columns.append(Column('c%d' % i, VARCHAR(1), nullable = False, server_default = '0'))
    columns.append(Column('d%d' % i, VARCHAR(2), nullable = False, server_default = '00'))


user = Table('user', metadata, *columns)
user.create(engine)

user2 = Table('user2', metadata, Column('c0', VARCHAR(100), nullable = False, server_default = '0' * 100),  \
                                 Column('d0', VARCHAR(200), nullable = False, server_default = '0' * 200))
user2.create(engine)
"""

many_columns = """
conn.execute(user.insert(), [{}] * 4000)
"""

two_columns = """
conn.execute(user2.insert(), [{}] * 4000)
"""

>>> timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.017949104309082031
>>> timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.047809123992919922
```

testing with sqlite3 module.

```
import timeit
setup = """
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE user (%s)' %\
    ("".join(("c%i VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, d%i VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '00' NOT NULL," % (index, index) for index in xrange(99))) +\
            "c99 VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, d99 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL"))

c.execute("CREATE TABLE user2 (c0 VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '%s' NOT NULL, d0 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '%s' NOT NULL)" % ('0'* 100, '0'*200))
conn.commit()
"""

many_columns = """
c.executemany('INSERT INTO user VALUES (%s)' % ('?,' * 199 + '?'), [('0', '00') * 100] * 4000)
conn.commit()
"""

two_columns = """
c.executemany('INSERT INTO user2 VALUES (?,?)', [('0'*100, '0'*200)] * 4000)
conn.commit()
"""

timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)

>>> timeit.Timer(many_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.14044189453125
>>> timeit.Timer(two_columns, setup).timeit(number = 1)
0.014360189437866211
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you excellent comment. I actually asked a related question [The insert speed of int and binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388729/the-insert-speed-of-int-and-binary). I tested the insert speed with the same table use sql and found that the insert is much fast for the table with more columns. Isn't it weird? @samy.vilar

Comment: @heller that is interesting, I did a quick simple test using default/blank inserts as well as filled, though using VARCHAR just to make sure no funny conv checks where occuring and well the one with two_columns was faster, so Im not sure whats going on it could MySQL thing, the article did say `InooDB was a lot slower`

Comment: you might find that if you access each column within each row like "[col for col in row]", the SQLAlchemy example will have some more overhead.   That's where per-column data processors kick in - though with SQLite we only use them with date types.   Also, glad you used just core here!  With ORM, the overhead is considerably more significant if full objects are being loaded.

Comment: So can we safely conclude that the number of columns do affect the performance of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: heller, I guess it really depends to what degree the affect is cause yes sqlalchemy in general does have an overhead, though I believe a constant one, for time anyway space maybe another story, correct me if I'm wrong @zzzeek, just comparing sqlalchemy and sqlite3 its a bit evident, I think it's safer to assume the overhead of a very wide table is much larger and more SQL implementation dependent, as such the performance hit will be noticed regardless of how you interface with ur database, this is what I was trying to emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

Samy.vilar's answer is excellent.  But one key thing to remember is that the number of columns will have an impact on the performance of any database and any ORM.  The more columns you have, the more data is being accessed from disk and transferred.

Also, depending on the query and table structures, adding more columns could change a query from being covered by an index to being forced to access the base table, which can add substantial time under certain databases and certain circumstances.

I have only played with SQLAlchemy a little bit, but as a DBA I generally advise the developers I work with to only query the columns that they will need and to avoid use of "select *" in production code, both because it is likely to contain more columns than needed and because it makes the code more brittle in the face of potential columns being added to the table/view.

Comment: thanks for the complement. he did make sure the rows where the same length regarding your statement `The more columns you have, the more data is being accessed from disk and transferred.` he was confounded by the fact that reading 100 1 byte and 2 byte columns (300 byte rows) would be far slower then reading 1 100 byte and 1 200 byte columns (again also 300 byte rows), he thought it wouldn't be much an issue, I think this is just the overhead most sql engines have when dealing with multiple columns in general it aggregates as the number of columns increases, though this is just a hunch...

Comment: Thanks, I apparantly didn't read deeply enough into it.  As you say, there is overhead associated with the columns.

Comment: +1 for the complement either way ;) and for trying to answer the question, I'am still a bit surprised about this, Im thinking it varies by implementation.

Comment: Thank both of you for your answers. Sorry that I do not have eough reputation to +1 for both of you. Thanks again! I guess Samy.vilar is right. However I am still curious about the phenomena in [The insert speed of int and binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388729/the-insert-speed-of-int-and-binary).